# Why doesn't hamon/Ripple slow down Joseph Joestar's aging?

Tags: anime, manga, jojos-bizarre-adventure

In *Part II: Battle Tendencies* of *Jojo's Bizarre Adventures*, the long-running manga series (and more relevantly to me, its ongoing anime adaptation of the same name) we learn that the martial arts technique known as **Hamon** (or the Ripple) enhances longevity and youthfulness of users, with Joseph's teacher ***Lisa Lisa*** and ***Straizo*** being the most obvious examples of this use of *Hamon*. By the end of the installment, Joseph has mastered the use of *Hamon* to a great extent.

But then when we we see him again **50 years later** in *Part III: Stardust Crusaders*, he's obviously nowhere near his prime, nor physically out of the normal range for a 67 year old, and most definitely ***looks his age***.

On the other hand, his daughter Holly, who's supposed to be 45 at this time, looks almost as young as 50 year-old Lisa Lisa during Part II (and Holly's youthful looks are explicitly remarked on in the first episode of Part III, so I'm assuming it's deliberate and

> given Lisa Lisa being Jojo's mom, I am also assuming there's a hereditary component to it if Holly benefits from it without being a *Hamon* user at all.

As such, why is Jojo so obviously aged, despite being a very proficient user of *Hamon*, while Holly looks young, despite her being not? (If my assumption about the reason for Holly's young looks is incorrect, please feel free to learn me :)

Is there any information in the manga, or from interviews or additional features from Araki?

Comment: Not everyone wants to live forever.

Comment: @Richard Does that mean the manga says that the slowed aging thing is something they have to _deliberately_ do, as opposed to a side-effect of being *Hamon* users/experts / the breathing technique?

Comment: The wiki suggests that you need to engage in daily exercise to stay rippled and that users can reject harmful substances inside of them "by ejecting it from their bloodstream with the use of Hamon energy". Possibly failing to practice regularly or refusing to reject substances would cause the anti-aging to fail?

Comment: @Richard Can you point me to where in the wiki this is said or maybe more importantly what the original source of that idea is? Couldn't find it...

Answer (score 3):

It's because Joseph hasn't been practicing his hamon for years after part 2. It's only if you continue your hamon training that you will age slower, or else, it will not work. Lisa Lisa, being a hamon master, hasn't aged and still looks twenty. Straizo was in his seventies, like Speedwagon, but still looked to be forty.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because he stopped practicing it after part 2. During part 3 in his fight against Empress, he said it was a long time since he's used hamon. After all, he's married and isn't a monk.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest joseph looks younger then he should be in part 3.even then he stopped hamon training.and straizo who should be around the same age as part 3 joseph will looks preddy old even with constant hamon training.

Comment: This doesn't clearly answer the question of why Hamon didn't slow down Joseph's aging.